# Timing issue with image upload on Heroku + Django Rest Framework + s3

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3

ok this is a mix of architecture design and code question.. I've had this problem on a couple of applications and I'm not sure how to handle this.

The problem is fairly basic, an app which allows users to attach files/images to an object.

Let's say I have the following Django models: `Document` and `Attachment`.

```
class Document(models.Model):

     body = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text='Plain text.')

class Attachment(models.Model):

     document = models.ForeignKey(Document, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='attachments')
     attachment = models.FileField(upload_to=get_attachment_path, max_length=255,  null=False)
     filesize = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     filetype = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
     orientation = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

The `get_attachment_path` callable simply builds a path based on the document pk and the user.

When a user creates a document, he can attach files to it. As it's a modern world, you want to be able to upload the files before creating the document, so I have a `TempUpload` object and a direct connection from the web application to S3 (using pre-signed URL).

When the user clicks `save` on the document form, I get an array of all the `TempUpload` objects that I need to attach to the new document.

Now here's the problem... within the heroku 30s timeout constraint, I need to:

- create the document (quite fast)
- iterate the array of `TempUpload` objects, and create the `Attachment`
- copy the file to its final destination (using boto3 `copy_object`)
- get the filetype (using the `magic` library, I only query the first 128 bytes, but still.. one roundtrip to S3)
- get the file size (another roundtrip to S3)
- get the orientation (only if the attachment is an image, also based on the EXIF data and using streaming)

I've already moved the thumbnail generation to an external service. But with bigger files (standard camera pictures can easily be 6-10Mb big), I can have processing delay of almost 1 sec per file, meaning that if the user uploads more than 20 images, it's getting very very close to the heroku timeout...

I'm currently using celery and redis to move most of the processing outside the response lifecycle, but it's not really nice... it can happen that the document is requested before the async task complete. in which case some info are not available yet (size/orientation).

I think that should actually be a fairly standard feature, I'd be interested to know how do you implement this ?

---

Edit:

Just to add some strategies I'm thinking of:

- get the info at the initial upload instead of when saving the document. This would work but the problem is that I don't know when the upload is completed (this happens directly between the web app and S3)
- use lambda fonction ?
- use S3 tags instead of moving the file to easily differentiate the "saved" files and the ones that should be deleted ?

For testing and dev I'd like to keep as much logic as possible within the django app.. but hey, maybe that's not possible...

Comment: can u use rabbitmq w 'django' ?  if yes then : https://github.com/heroku-examples/node-articles-nlp/blob/master/lib/app/index.js#L48  is from node proj. on heroku using Heroku.background workers ( NO H12 timeout at 30 seconds ). But u will have to finesse the issue of how to get the CDN URL for the POST on photo-file back to the client from the heroku 'worker'..  there are alternate ways of managing state that alow u todo that and to have the client 'fetch' the doc later where doc (at that later pt. in time) will include an array of the URLs on the CDN resulting from the Async Posts to S3.

Comment: first understand the Heroku timeouts : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing    i dont 'django' so maybe use the Python implementation from Heroku modules on git??   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq